# JavaScript - Regex to remove code / special characters / numbers etc

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Answer  @Wiktor Stribiżew suggested:

```
function myValidate(word) {
    return (word.length === 1 || /[^A-Z]/i.test(word)) ? true : false;
    }
```

---

Hello during the creation of an array I have a function that will not allow words with certain characters etc to be added to the array

```
    function myValidate(word) {
        // No one letter words
        if (word.length === 1) {
            return true;
        }
        if (word.indexOf('^') > -1 || word.indexOf('$') > -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

It seems like not the proper way of going about this and ive been looking into a regex that would handle it but have not been successful implementing it, tried numerous efforts like:

```
if (word.match('/[^A-Za-z]+/g') ) {
            return true;
        }
```

can some one shed some light on the proper way of handling this?

Comment: Define *special characters* ? Or tell us what characters are acceptable and what aren't. Also please provide a few example.

Comment: this function iterates through an array called "words" which holds elements called "word". 

Each "word" element is a word scraped from a random website.

In doing the scraping, you can be left with undesirable results at times, so I am validating these are actual words by ensuring that they have no special characters or numbers etc before they enter the array.  if the variable "word" is caught with something that is not A-Za-z, then we return true, which tells the array builder to ignore it

Comment: Aren't you looking for [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/64fs5wdj/)?

Comment: `/\b\W+\b/g` should be your regexp as i can get from the limited information that you provide.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes that is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using  a simpler solution:

```js
function myValidate(word) { 
  return (word.length === 1 || /[^A-Z]/i.test(word)) ? false : true;
}
var words = ["Fat", "Gnat", "x3-2741996", "1996", "user[50]", "definitions(edit)", "synopsis)"];
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(words.filter(x => myValidate(x)));
```

Where:

- `word.length === 1` checks for the string length
- `/[^A-Z]/i.test(word)` checks if there is a non-ASCII-letter symbol in the string

If any of the above condition is met, the word is taken out of the array. The rest remains.

Comment: had to swap the false with the true for my situation, but this worked great, thanks! 

`return (word.length === 1 || /[^A-Z]/i.test(word)) ? true : false;`

Comment: Yes, I just used the "false : true" order for the `.filter()` function.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** using `test` instead of `match`

You want to use `test()` because it returns a bool telling you if you match the regex or not. The `match()`, instead, always returns the matched elements. Those may be cast to `true` by coercion. This is not what you want.

To sum it all up you can just use this one-liner (no `if` needed and no quotes either, cannot get any simpler):

```
return word.test(/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]+$/); // two letter words
```

---

You should whitelist characters instead of blacklisting. That's one of the principles in security. In your case, don't tell what is wrong, but tell what is right:

```
if (word.test('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/')) { // two letter words
    return false;
}
```

This will return false for all words that contain ONLY `[a-zA-Z]` characters. I guess this is what you want.

Your regex, instead, looked for illegal characters by negating the character group with the leading `^`.

---

Two recommendations:

1. Just use regex in a positive way (without negation) and it'll be a lot easier to understand.
2. Also, validation functions normally return `true` for good data and `false` for bad data.

It is more readable this way:

```
if (validate(data))
{
    // that's some good data we have here!
}
```

Comment: This looks like it would be right and what im going for, but it is not working.

Comment: Ok. It means: from start to end, at least 1 character, only in the designated range. Are you sure there are no other characters? like spaces or digits?

Comment: my array is still getting word elements like : "x3-2741996", "1996", "user[50]", "definitions(edit)", "synopsis)"

Comment: Use `test()`. Look at my edit and let's see if it works now.

Comment: By the way, this regex still matches one letter words. If you want at least 2 letter words you must use this regex: `/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]+$/`